# Rotating a 3d object in a top down shooter

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I am trying to make a very simple top-down shooter. As an example I currently have a 3d box that I am trying to get the player's mouse position and rotate the box's z axis towards that angle. I have a few small ideas of how to approach this but I can't really seem to put it together in valid code. Can someone lend a hand?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveOnAxisInput : MonoBehaviour
{
public string horizontalAxis = "Horizontal";
public string verticalAxis = "Vertical";
public float speed = 1.0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    transform.position += (Vector3.right*Input.GetAxis(horizontalAxis) + Vector3.forward*Input.GetAxis(verticalAxis)).normalized*speed*Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(0, 10, Input.mousePosition.z);
    Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
    lookPos = lookPos - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookPos.z, lookPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining mouse position is not working with your code here:

```
Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(0, 10, Input.mousePosition.z);
```

Try using instead:

```
Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
                               Input.mousePosition.y,
                               1f);
```

When using Input.mousePosition, you get a Vector3 containing pixel coordinates in the x and y, along with a z component of 0.

Additionally, since you are attempting to make a top-down shooter, try using AngleAxis with Vector3.up instead of Vector3.forward. This will make your character rotate around the Y axis.

Here is the final code which worked for me in a test scene:

```
Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
                               Input.mousePosition.y,
                               1f);
Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
lookPos = lookPos - transform.position;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookPos.z, lookPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-angle, Vector3.up);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man! Sometimes I guess everyone needs a little help :)

Comment: Another question. This one applies a continuous rotation towards my game object. Is their any way to make it get the position of the mouse and stop?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Top Down Game Basics Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/top-down-2d)
.

Though it is about 2D yet helps a lot in making Top-Down Game.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out in a bit!

Comment: Okay! Let me know if its helpful or if you have any other question regarding this.

Comment: It seems the video with your solution has my actual solution. Sadly the one above just applied a continuous rotation. Thanks!